# How to find latitude & longitude in Google maps in place description?

Tags: google-maps, location, latitude-longitude

I want to use the values of long & lat of some famous places in my app. I can find long & lat on the map by methods described in this link: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en.

But these methods don't give long & lat of some pin. So, How to find latitude & longitude of some famous place in place description or some where else without right clicking multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

When you type a famous place in google maps search box, it takes you to that place but doesn't provide you any co-ordinates.

In order to get exact co-ordinates:

1. Left click any where near the place then a pop-up will appear at the page bottom.
2. Click on the co-ordinates which will populate the side navigation
   with co-ordinates.
3. Then just select & copy it.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question description I tried this but it won't give you exact lat-long of that place.

Comment: Try to zoom in as much as possible & then left click on the map, this method will work.

Comment: I have done this and all possible methods at my end but nothing works. It gives just nearby coordinate.